# Stop sending the access token with the response body in Yii2

Tags: rest, authentication, yii2, bearer-token

I am developing a rest API using Yii2, the front end is developed by ionic.
the case is that when I have an action which it uses bearer authentication.. 
it works fine but the access token is returned with the response body which leads to an HttpErrorResponse in the client side:

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token y in JSON at position 0 at Json.parse
```

the response is returned like this so the client is not able to parse the json

```
 y2sSCEXqkUoVY2BjkQZqx8g3W42273Cz{"success":false,"message":"you liked it before"}
```

this is the behaviour code which uses the bearear authentication

```
  public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];
    // remove authentication filter
    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
    // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => CorsCustom::className(),
    ];
    // re-add authentication filter
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
    // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        'only' => ['like', 'unlike', 'likes', 'create'],
        'authMethods' => [
            HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        ],
        ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

I want to stop sending the access token in the body or send it as a json

Comment: :v..................

Answer (score 3):

Stop `echo` the token before the response and you'll get your job DONE!

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    /* echo $token; */
    return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should remove the `echo $token` statement from your USER model

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    /* echo $token; */
    return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
}
```